# Do right wing libertarians have a mechanism which incentivises long term planning?

Tags: libertarianism, city-planning, planning

Some right wing libertarians intend to have the world run primarily, if not totally, on market-forces which in the vast majority of cases favor short-term gains and do not usually take into account outcomes, (*e.g.* polluting neighboring communities, plastic waste passing through the ocean food chain back to us, climate change, traffic due to lack of focus on dense public transportation, *etc.*), for people who are not their consumers.

Do these libertarians, who would do away with civil planning in favor of business strategy, have strategies to deal with long term problems, some of which need foresight extending beyond the end of the lives of the ones doing the planning? Strategies I am over-looking?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but I want to point out that democracy in itself also does not incentivise planning much beyond the next 1-2 terms. Yet, it still happens.

Comment: Can you please add details or clarity? In its current form the question is a bit vauge

Comment: I doubt the question can be answered objectively. If [this example](https://newrepublic.com/article/159662/libertarian-walks-into-bear-book-review-free-town-project) is any indication, long-term planning (or any kind of planning) is not a top priority for libertarians.

Comment: @Erwan really funny book.  and I agree with you.  at the same time, not sure how well it scales out from a partial takeover of a small rural backwater to bigger politics.

Comment: I don't see why whatever mechanism we might have in place now in western democracies would necessarily be absent libertarian ones. People can still collaborate and form contracts - it's just that these won't be forced on every single individual.

Comment: The kind of problems you list are known as "Tragedy of the Commons". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons

Comment: Desire for long-term profits.

Answer (score 8):

Right-Libertarians (as a general rule) rely on an expansive conception of the *invisible hand of the market*. In other words, They follow this logic:

1. Every interaction with the world at large will ultimately reduce to a human social interaction
2. Every human social interaction will ultimately reduce to an economic interaction
3. Every economic interaction is subject to market forces, which will ultimately balance and resolve problems through competition

In that sense, long-term planning is unnecessary, even counterproductive. Short-term selfish actions are circular and self-referential: as one acts with short-term selfish goals, one alters the natural world, which alters human social interactions, which alters the market, which in turn alters what constitutes a 'selfish' action. Today I pollute the environment. That creates social opposition from the people I dump pollutants on (who selfishly dislike that). And *that* generates a new competitive market for people who (selfishly) believe they can profit by cleaning up the mess I made.

It's all a bit like [Zorg's speech](https://youtu.be/krcNIWPkNzA) from "The Fifth Element". I don't agree with it, or condone it, but Right-Libertarians rarely ask me for my opinion. So...

Comment: Considering you’re not the one supporting this view, I can’t very well argue it’s merits with you, so I’ll probably accept it if no better contenders stroll into town.

Comment: @Ethan: It's a somewhat tough question to get a 'horses-mouth' answer on. Libertarians are not an overly philosophically inclined group. They don't deeply analyze their own belief system the way some other political ideologies do, and they don't much like it when others do the analysis for them. But here's hoping someone in the worldview gives it a go...

Comment: I think the second part of the correction argument is that consumers will opt to buy from companies that pollute less if pollution is a problem, thus incentivizing companies to adapt.  Granted, today they adapt by shipping the production or even the waste itself to East Asia, but baby steps.  I also disagree that the linked video represents Libertarianism, Zorg appears to be a government-like actor doing the equivalent of Paul Krugman's "Pay people to fill holes and dig them up" theory (I haven't watched the movie, so just basing on that scene).

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: It's one of my favorite films; well worth the watch if you like sci-fi. And in the film's context Zorg is clearly meant to a caricature of an evil industrialist. Hut you're right, that's not really evident from the clip. I just thought the speech was on point.

Comment: What stops a libertarian from including sustainability in their list of selfish wants?

Comment: @StopBeingEvil: Technically, nothing stops a Libertarian from from valuing sustainability. Pragmatically, sustainability appears as a 'doing for others' that comes at a distinct personal cost. It's a kind of welfare for the planet, and it takes a decent amount of philosophical juggling to work oneself around to the position that sustainability is a 'selfish' virtue. And as I said, Libertarians are not overly inclined towards philosophy...

Comment: Would a libertarian that *does* view sustainability as a selfish virtue still be a libertarian, then? There's been a lot of pointing out that other systems also don't meet this standard, and while I don't buy the whataboutism, I do think there's a tendency here to ascribe beliefs to libertarianism when they should be ascribed to jerks in general.

Comment: @StopBeingEvil: Meh, I rarely stereotype in such broad strokes. Most Right-Libertarian (I imagine) are decent people who are perfectly happy to give up this or that for the benefit of others. They see it as ethically correct, and value kindness and generosity. The difficulty is that the ideology doesn't explicitly encourage or reward such an attitude, and tends to attract people who are narcissistically (pathologically) selfish. As you say, there are jerks in every camp; Right-Libertarians just tend to put them as pack leaders...

Comment: Libertarians usually regard coercion and violence as public evils, the civic harms of which outweigh their perpetrators self interest.    Libertarian pollution disputes usually tend revolve around the polluter's aggressively ignorant skepticism, (either polluters either don't know better, and wrongly believe pollutants to be harmless, or they know but criminally pretend otherwise); Libertarians do not approve of *knowingly* poisoning their neighbors.  So this answer's usage of "selfish" to signify disapproval of being poisoned is too broad.

Comment: @agc: In my experience, there are two kinds of Right-Libertarians: those who overtly respect the rights and liberties of their fellow citizens,  and those who insist that it is the responsibility of fellow citizens to demand and defend their rights and liberties. Libertarianism itself does not distinguish between these groups (sometimes voicing one opinion, sometimes the other, seemingly according to mood), but the second group would contentedly dump poisonous waste in their neighbor's yard, on the justification that the neighbor failed to make them stop.

Comment: @agc: Libertarians of the first sort do not approve of knowingly poisoning their neighbors. Libertarians of the second sort will respect anyone who has the wherewithal to make them *stop* poisoning their neighbors, but honestly don't give a flying fig if their neighbors get poisoned. That would be their neighbor's problem... When Libertarianism grows up enough to have a consistent moral worldview, it will be a respectable philosophy, and will immediately be dropped by the majority of people who currently avow it. Such is life...

Comment: Libertarians assume that individuals have perfect knowledge, that no ideology or hegemonic forces influence the minds of individuals.  The ideology itself is devoid of context and reality.

Comment: @TedWrigley, It looks as though that "second sort" elaboration conflates Libertarians and *criminals*, or perhaps that subset of modern corporate criminals who use Libertarianism as their figleaf *du jour*.   But a moth that from a certain angle resembles a barn owl is not an owl.  OTOH, it's hard to think of any notable political party or religion that hasn't been the occasional beneficiary of wealthy criminals who use it as camouflage.

Comment: @agc: Libertarianism's definition of 'criminality' is vague and squidgy; the only real crime seems to be use-of-force (variously defined). If I have a production process that produces hazardous byproducts and I dump them in a nearby river, I am not (according to many Right-Libertarians) using any sort of force at all. If other people don't have the sense not to drink polluted river-water... Libertarians seems to have a bit of a cottage industry explaining how they would never do anything against the interests of other people, but that is all a bit utopian, don't you think?

Comment: @TedWrigley, No, not utopian -- criminal, or *dys*topian.  This answer would be better it provided an illustrative representative example of a Libertarian, or Corporate Crook or Oblivious Kook "Libertarian" railing against the folly of drinking downstream from a polluting factory... or at least a URL to an example.

Comment: @agc: Do you want me to point at Ayn Rand's belief that American Indians deserved to have their land taken away, because colonial whites made better use of it? Do you need an exhaustive list of the economic opinions of Milton Friedman or Paul Ryan? But honestly, I don't see why I should need to provide examples. If you can state some explicit, generally accepted tenet of Libertarianism that precludes this unpleasant behavior then I'll cede the point on ideological grounds. Show me something that a dedicated narcissist can't weasel-word into anti-social behavior. No worries, I'll wait...

Comment: @TedWrigley, For a respectable Libertarian tenet giver contemplating social limits, try this WP summary of [Robert Nozick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy,_State,_and_Utopia#Prohibition,_compensation,_and_risk)'s views.  Re *"Show me something..."*: can't be done -- no political, legal, or ethical system is immune to being perversely and gainfully disinterpreted  by conclaves of malevolent characters.

Comment: @agc: I'm not overly familiar with Nozick's work, but from that summary even *he* is not claiming to establish a principle (see the last quote of that section). He merely posits that such a principle exists, and asserts he is at the beginning of working it out. And that's my point. Christianity has a firm principle "Thou shalt not steal" so they can effectively say that someone who steals a lot is not acting like a good Christian. Where is the Libertarian principle that says "Thou shalt not pollute a waterway?" so that we can say polluters are not good Libertarians?

Comment: @TedWrigley, Libertarians revere Lockean property rights, so they dislike theft, (however they define "theft"); and from that axiom some Libertarians argue the upstream polluter initiates aggression by lowering the property values, and interfering with the property rights, of their neighbors without consent.   (Argument found on Libertarian Environmentalist site [FREEcology, discussing North Carolina hog farms](https://libertarianenvironmentalism.com/2020/02/04/federal-judge-in-environmental-nuisance-case-less-fortunate-citizens-have-property-rights-too/).)

Comment: @agc: I understand, and I'm really not trying to undercut Libertarianism. Right-Libertarianism isn't *wrong*; Right-Libertarianism is *under-theorized*, and thus prone to ambiguities, lacuna, and inconsistencies. If it had a proper theoretical basis, you wouldn't be forced into statements like "Some libertarians argue..." on basic concepts like this. People like Nozick are an important part of that process, but as of now there's no 'there' there. It has no firm mechanism for setting the bad apples apart from the good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127162/discussion-between-agc-and-ted-wrigley).

Comment: The long paragraph implies the people who pay for the cleanup are the victims, not the perpetrators of the pollution. It says the pollution will be resolved, but it doesn't say it'll be resolved fairly. Is that correct?

Comment: @user253751: Well, not quite. It implies that the people affected by the the solution will take (self-interested) action, but that action might be social, political, or legal action against the polluter. In the Right-Libertarian mythos, all competitive outcomes are intrinsically fair; or rather, the concept of 'fairness' is indistinguishable from '*laissez faire*' outcomes.

Answer (score 3):

First, a bit of a frame challenge.  You say the free market cannot plan long-term, but neglect the fact that the government struggles with it quite often as well.  Remember when Osama Bin Laden was an ally of the US and we gave the Taliban all those weapons?  Remember when [Los Angeles basically stole all the water from the Owens Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_water_wars)?  Remember when the Soviets almost completely drained the [Aral Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aral_Sea)?

Libertarianism is not anarchism.  Only the most extreme libertarians think people should be allowed to dump pollution wherever they please or whatever.  I can't think of a negative externality that doesn't have clearly defined person or class of people who could sue in response.  The fishing industry can sue waste management companies for letting plastic refuse ruin their fisheries, a town could sue a factory over the negative effects of the smog it produces, etc.  Avoiding these lawsuits is a perfectly adequate motive to convince people to plan long-term.

Comment: Your second sentence appears to contain a false dichotomy?

Comment: @user253751 what is the third option I'm missing?

Comment: Looking at lawsuits over the years it seems very obvious that resolution by lawsuit is a suboptimal solution.
Even if you can prove that X company polluted Y waterway, how do you *prove* it is *their* pollution caused your current problem? Not to mention the typical problem in these scenarios of vastly different legal budgets.

Comment: @Trasvi But is it worse than the centrally planned problem?  It's taken over 100 years for the Owens Valley water situation to get worked out and it's still not really fixed.  Pretty sure the US government never did anything about all those times the Army sprayed carcinogens over US cities in some kind of nuclear fallout experiment.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_LAC
I don't think it is clear that centrally-planned actions have better outcomes or cause fewer negative externalities.

Comment: @Ryan_L It seems pretty clear to me. Consider the history of food adulteration under a free market. https://victorianweb.org/science/health/health1.html

Comment: @PaulJohnson And yet sometimes in a centrally-planned economy you can't get any food, see the Holodomor.

Comment: @Ryan_L So the best solution seems to be a mixture. Private enterprise under government regulation seems to be the best way of delivering a wide range of non-toxic food in quantities that people want to buy.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Agreed, though I don't know how meaningful that statement is.  The question still stands, "How much regulation is too much?"

Comment: @Ryan_L Regulation is not "more" or "less" it is "better" or "worse". Good regulations  achieve their objectives without imposing unnecessary costs. Bad regulations impose extra costs while failing to meet their objectives. Asking "How much regulation?" is a bit like asking "How much should an aircraft weigh?".

Comment: and for @PaulJohnson's reason a quick turnaround time on regulation is probably essential, so that bad regulations can get weeded out or turned into good ones.

Answer (score 2):

I'll extend Ted's answer one level, but I will also not give any references because I didn't research whether such argument is actually put forth by libertarians. (At least, in politics. I've seen it debated in software development). Nevertheless, it's a valid argument, to an extent, and I find it more compelling than the simple feedback mechanism known as "the invisible hand of the market".

In a word, development (especially long-term!) happens like **evolution**. In evolution, the feedback to the next generation is the traits and properties that "happen" to be aligned with successful social interactions (e.g. business practices). The good thing about evolution is that the "actors" (people, businesses, etc.) don't even need to *know* what caused the success (or failure). They just need to "inherit" such practices and, basically, do the same if they succeed and not do it if they fail.

Evolution is seemingly a very short-sighted process. It can't "plan" anything. Yet, as any research into evolutionary optimisation shows, it's an amazingly robust process, and on complex landscapes evolutionary methods nearly always beat deterministic optimisation. (And what can be more complex than human societies?) Evolution is the only known "natural" process that can *create* new information.

Now, for evolutionary model to work, several conditions must be true. First, there must be competition. ("Selection pressure" in evolutionary terms). The more actors, the better. Whoever loses must fail.<sup>1</sup> Next, actors must be able to freely interact with each other and "borrow" successful traits. And that's it.

Generally, evolutionary process doesn't "like" rational interaction, like the elitist selection mentioned in the footnote<sup>1</sup>. It is quite counter-intuitive, especially for an "engineering" mind. It doesn't favour parsimonious, that is, the simplest and most "elegant" solutions. But this, it seems, quite aligns with libertarian mind.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Must" should not be taken too literally here. Evolution is brutal but messy thing. It can be shown that in most cases non-deterministic selection (where successful individuals/practices simply have *more chances* to pass onto the next generation) is more efficient and robust than the so called "elitist" selection where exactly the best ones are always selected.

Comment: Evolution requires room to fail. A company deciding that nuking the rainforests is a great idea will eventually be proven wrong, but the damage it causes before it dies might well be irreparable.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Central planning has caused plenty of ecological disasters too.  I don't think "a company might be evil once" is a good criticism because we have plenty of examples of governments being evil too.  We can make the same arguments in the other direction.  Remember when the US government sprayed radioactive material over American and Canadian cities as part of nuclear research? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unethical_human_experimentation_in_the_United_States#Human_radiation_experiments
Clearly this is evidence that only private institutions should be doing research /sarcasm

Comment: @Ryan_L I don't think they're arguing that governments are always good or that corporations are always bad – they can both do great evils, which is why there needs to be systems to regulate them to prevent that. Democracy attempts to do that for government (though it's obviously far from perfect), but for private companies there isn't a great (purely libertarian) solution. Evolutionary processes _might_ work in the long term, but the price of these destructive mistakes working themselves out (without any system to prevent them from occurring in the first place) would be huge.

Comment: @Ryan_L Why do you argue against someone who thinks X fails, by bringing up Y? That is known as "whataboutism". "Didn't you murder hundreds of thousands of innocent civilians?" "Well yes I did, but what about that time *your* predecessor murdered hundreds of thousands of innocent civilians?"